# What is a Taub–NUT space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology

I trying to read and understand the [Taub–NUT space](https://wiki2.org/en/Taub%E2%80%93NUT_space). Wikipedia introduced that it is associated with the Taub–NUT metric, an exact solution to Einstein's equations. However, I didn't find a direct explanation of the physical meanings of Taub–NUT space, and its relations with General Relativity. Can anyone give me some hints about that?

Comment: Chapter 5 of the book *The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime*, by Hawking & Ellis, discusses Taub-NUT if I recall correctly

Comment: @Níckolas Alves  Is it fair for me to say the Taub–NUT space is a mathematical solution in the framework of General Relativity?

Comment: certainly. I never studied Taub-NUT in depth, so I can't really say much of why it is interesting, but in fact any Lorentzian manifold is a solution of the Einstein Equations for some stress tensor (which might not be physically meaningful). I have no doubt that Taub-NUT is a solution of the equations of General Relativity, but I haven't studied it well enough to say in which contexts it appears or for what reasons

Comment: On a more pedagogical level, the Taub-NUT spacetime is the four dimensional version of Misner space, for which there are more ressources